# Knockout functions are not working when published

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js

I have developed a site in mvc. I have used knockout in client side. The problem is no any issue in debug and release modes. But some knockout functions are not working when site published. What is the problem can be? plz help me...

Comment: any errors is console , can you tell us when you try to run it (published mode) .

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be related to the location of knockout.js due to the mistake of path definition. Check these and let me know if it works:

1) In te project be sure that script definitions has been made like that:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/knockout.js")"></script>
```

2) Alternatively check the other content i.e. css classes:

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

3) Be sure that js, css, and the other content files are published to the publish directory.

4) At last step check if these content files can be loaded to the browser by using Firebug or etc.

Hope this helps...